# Is XP Themes necessary for XP to run properly?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

My boot management software allows me to delay or remove various software that is now a part of my boot process. I am attempting to remove any programs not necessary to me.

Can XP themes be safely removed from mky boot process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd assume they are referring to the "themes" service. I keep this disabled on XP anyway as I have no use for the eye candy. Hasn't ever caused me trouble :)

So to answer your question, no it is not necessary.